# How can I add an extension to multiple file names?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have a folder containing multiple files with names like:

```
pnahc.d_m05d17h09m30
```

I want to place an extension at the end of the filename so that the new filename looks like:

```
pnahc.d_m05d17h09m30.txt
```

I tried using `ren *. *.txt`, but it did not work. How can I do this?

Comment: You could possibly use a `FOR` loop.

Comment: Does "REN *   *.TXT" work? The wildcard "/*." would imply any filename that ends in a period. I can't try it on this PC, but I seem to remember it working in XP.

Comment: Does "REN star star.TXT" work? The wildcard "star." would imply any filename that ends in a period. I can't try it on this PC, but I seem to remember it working in XP. Sorry for the "star"s as I cannot figure out any other way to prevent it from turning into italics

Comment: @hdhondt Enclose it in backticks to indicate an inline code block (`\`<code goes here>\``). If you ever want to use an asterisk in normal text, insert a backslash before it: `\*hello\*` so you can have something like this: \*hello\*

Answer (score 19):

According to [this](http://tweaks.com/windows/49459/batch-file-rename-with-windows-powershell/) page you could try running these commands in [powershell](http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/) (search for it in the windows start menu):

```
cd "\path\to\dir"
Dir | rename-item -newname  { $_.Name +".jpg" }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Bulkrename](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php) can do it, first "remove" the extension, hit rename then hit reset, then add the one you want using the "extra" function. You can do this for multiple files in the same folder.

.
[image]

.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for names that have periods in them.

Comment: Actually it does, i do it all the time with that software.

Comment: Only for you. When I rename stuff with periods the names get all screwed up. Try adding an extension to something with a period in it and it adds it at that period rather than the end.

Comment: There are options there to add or remove only from the start, only from the end, only from a specific position in the name. You can see the options in the screenshot above, right in the middle box "Remove (5)". And that's not even getting into the realm of regex...

Comment: If you don't know how to use this software, don't blame me.

Answer (score 2):

A single command line command will do the trick:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b') do @ren "%a" "%a.txt"
```

Just change into the folder with the files.

Comment: @nandha kumar asks: Thank you Multiverse IT. Please explain your command.

Answer (score 0):

Can do it easily with PowerShell.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Directory | ? {!$_.PSIsContainer} | % {Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.Name -NewName ($_.Name + ".txt")}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do it with [JP Software's TCC](http://jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm), a command interpreter whose `REN` command supports regular expressions:

```
ren ::(.*) ::\1.txt
```

Without regular expressions, it's still a one-liner.  TCC supports the same `FOR` syntax as Microsoft's `cmd`, so one could use the `FOR` one-liner from `Multiverse IT`'s answer.

With all of the command-line answers here, by the way, note that it's important that scanning the directory precede any rename operations if possible.  You weren't specific enough in your question about the original filenames, so in our answers we've had to assume that *every file* is to be processed.  The search wildcards will therefore *match the resultant filenames as well*, ending up with files potentially being renamed multiple times, if one isn't careful.

If one knew that the source filenames only contained one dot, say, then one could construct a more restrictive search wildcard that didn't match the resultant filenames that have two dots.  Using the non-regular expression form of TCC's `ren` command this would be:

```
ren *.*. *.*.txt
```

The trailing dot in the search wildcard is important.  (`.` is actually a metacharacter in search wildcards, although very few people document it.  It matches *either* a `.` *or* the end of a name.)  It matches the ends of the names, and prevents the preceding `*` from matching a dot.

### Further reading

- JP Software. [*REN*](http://jpsoft.com/help/ren.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.
- JP Software. [*FOR*](http://jpsoft.com/help/for.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.